Equivalence of Sobolev spaces Definitions on Riemannian manifold via $k$-Covariant Derivative and $k$-Gradient Derivative
I am studying Sobolev spaces on Riemannian manifolds and have encountered two different definitions in the literature.
In the references:

E. Hebey. Nonlinear analysis on manifolds: Sobolev spaces and inequalities, volume 5 of Courant Lect. Notes Math. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS); New York, NY: Courant Institute of Mathematical Sciences, New York Univ., 2000.
T. Aubin. Nonlinear analysis on manifolds. Monge-Ampère equations, volume 252 of Grundlehren Math. Wiss. Springer, Cham, 1982.

the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(M)$ is defined as the completion of
$$
\mathcal C_{co}^{k,p}(M):=\left\{u\in C^\infty(M)\colon \int_M|\nabla_{co}^ku|^p\mathrm dv(g)<\infty\mbox{ for each }j=0,\ldots,k\right\}$$
under the norm
$$
\|u\|_{co,W^{k,p}}=\left(\sum_{j=0}^k\int_M|\nabla^j_{co}u|^p\mathrm dv(g)\right)^{\frac{1}{p}},
$$
where $\nabla_{co}^ku$  is the $k$-covariant tensor (the $k$-covariant derivative of $u$).
However, I have recently come across another definition where the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(M)$ is defined as the completion of
$$
\mathcal C^{k,p}_{gr}(M):=\left\{u\in C^\infty(M)\colon \int_M|\nabla_{gr}^ku|^p\mathrm dv(g)<\infty\mbox{ for each }j=0,\ldots,k\right\},
$$
under the norm
$$
\|u\|_{gr,W^{k,p}}=\left(\sum_{j=0}^k\int_M|\nabla^j_{gr}u|^p\mathrm dv(g)\right)^{\frac{1}{p}},
$$
where $\nabla_{gr}^ku$ is the $k$-gradient of $u$ defined as:
$$
\nabla^k_{gr}u=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
         \Delta^{\frac{k}{2}}u,&\mbox{if }k\mbox{ is even},\\
         \nabla(\Delta^{\frac{k-1}2}u),&\mbox{if }k\mbox{ is odd},
         \end{array}\right.
$$
with $\nabla$ being the gradient and $\Delta$ the Laplace-Beltrami operator. I have used the subscript "co" for the covariant definition and "gr" for the gradient definition.
My question is: Why do these definitions coincide? Is there a reference that explains this equivalence? I have attempted to prove that $\|u\|_{co,W^{k,p}}$ is equivalent to $\|u\|_{gr,W^{k,p}}$ in $\mathcal C_{co}^{k,p}(M)\cap\mathcal C_{gr}^{k,p}(M)$, but I have only succeeded for $k=1$ (which is straightforward).
Any insights or references on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

You need to use the equivalent estimates where $u$ is a tensor instead of just a scalar function. This follows by Kato's inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kato's_inequality).

No, it does not follow from Kato's inequality.

OK. Any chance you could identify a specific step where you get stuck?

I found a paper by Aubin from 1976 which, assuming $M$ is complete and under certain curvature hypotheses (denoted by $\mathcal H^{k-2}$), shows some embeddings between those spaces. You can have more information about the paper using the following zbMATH link:

Espaces de Sobolev sur les variétés riemanniennes

